# JS: Replacing all string values in an object that match a pattern?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for an efficient way to replace the values within an object if they match a certain pattern.

```
var shapes = {
  square: {
    attr: {
      stroke: '###',
      'stroke-width': '%%%'
    }
  },
  circle: {
    attr: {
      fill: '###',
      'stroke-width': '%%%'
    }
  }
}
```

For instance, i'd like to be able to replace all '###' patterns with a colour for a specific shape:

```
var square = replace(shapes.square, {
  '###': '#333',
  '%%%': 23
});

var circle = replace(shapes.circle, {
  '###': '#111',
  '%%%': 5
});
```

Which would allow me quickly to set the stroke and/or fill values of various objects.

Is there a way to do this cleanly? Perhaps using Lodash or regex?

Comment: what version of lodash are you using?

Comment: Using the latest version

Answer (score 8):

Plain JS, no library needed:

```js
var shapes = {
  square: {
    attr: {
      stroke: '###',
      'stroke-width': '%%%'
    }
  },
  circle: {
    attr: {
      fill: '###',
      'stroke-width': '%%%'
    }
  }
}
shapes = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(shapes).replace(/###/g,"red").replace(/%%%/g,"23")
)
console.log(shapes);
```

Answer (score 6):

In lodash, you have a utility function [`mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mapValues)

```
function replaceStringsInObject(obj, findStr, replaceStr) {
  return _.mapValues(obj, function(value){
    if(_.isString(value)){
      return value.replace(RegEx(findStr, 'gi'), replaceStr);
    } else if(_.isObject(value)){
      return replaceStringInObject(value, findStr, replaceStr);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on [meir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40380448/1929671) (getting rid of lodash dependency and circular processing):

```
function replaceStringsInObject(obj, findStr, replaceStr, cache = new Map()) {
    if (cache && cache.has(obj)) return cache.get(obj);

    const result = {};

    cache && cache.set(obj, result);

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        let v = null;

        if(typeof value === 'string'){
            v = value.replace(RegExp(findStr, 'gi'), replaceStr);
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            v = value;
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                v[i] = replaceStringsInObject(value, findStr, replaceStr, cache);
            }
        }
        else if(typeof value === 'object'){
            v = replaceStringsInObject(value, findStr, replaceStr, cache);
        }
        else {
            v = value;
        }
        result[key] = v;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) API should allow you to do exactly that!

You'd have to walk the properties of the object first, but that should be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the code given by Quentin.

- It doesn't use the cache (so watch out for circles!)
- It works on any object, e.g. strings, directly.
- It does whole-string replacement only.
- It replaces strings found in the keys of an object.
- It has special cases to leave certain Firebase objects intact, e.g. Timestamp. This is easily extended to include other types of direct-copy

```js
function replaceStringsInObject(value, findStr, replaceStr) {
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    return findStr === value ? replaceStr : value;
  } else if (value instanceof admin.firestore.Timestamp) {
    return value;
  } else if (value instanceof admin.firestore.GeoPoint) {
    return value;
  } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map((arrayItem) =>
      replaceStringsInObject(arrayItem, findStr, replaceStr)
    );
  } else if (typeof value === "object") {
    const newObj = {};
    for (let [key, oldInnerValue] of Object.entries(value)) {
      const newInnerValue = replaceStringsInObject(
        oldInnerValue,
        findStr,
        replaceStr
      );
      const newKey = key === findStr ? replaceStr : key;
      newObj[newKey] = newInnerValue;
    }
    return newObj;
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [_.transform](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#transform) in order to substitute the value of the attribute by the one passed in the object of replacements. In case of the value not being in the replacements, the original value is used.

```js
function replace(src, repl) {
  return {
    attr: _.transform(src.attr, function(result, val, key) {
      result[key] = repl[val] || val;
    }, {})
  };
}

var shapes = {
  square: {
    attr: {
      stroke: '###',
      'stroke-width': '%%%'
    }
  },
  circle: {
    attr: {
      fill: '###',
      'stroke-width': '%%%'
    }
  }
};

var square = replace(shapes.square, {
  '###': '#333',
  '%%%': 23
});

var circle = replace(shapes.circle, {
  '###': '#111',
  '%%%': 5
});

console.log(square);
console.log(circle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```