# MongoDB, Node: Query ISODate fields with a query not build directly in find operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, isodate

I am using nodejs with the official [mongodb driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb).

I have documents with a date property stored as ISODate type.

The query is built beforehand and stored as a string ex. `'{createdAt: {$gte: "FROM_DATE", $lte: "TO_DATE"}}'` and passed onto server together with variables for `fromDate` and `toDate`.

There the query is parsed using [json5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5) and `"FROM_DATE"` is replaced by `new Date(fromDate)` and same for the other.

The problem is `new Date(fromDate)` is always stored as string and I end up with the query below:

```
{createdAt: {
  $gte: 'Tue Mar 10 2020 22:23:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)',
  $lte: 'Thu Apr 09 2020 22:23:51 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)'
}}
```

Which as string it won't query ISODate format.

Is it just because I'm replacing string it gets returned as string by default or where is the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toISOString function while creating a date, as shown below

```
const date = new Date('01-JAN-2020');
console.log(date)
//Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

const newDate = new Date('01-JAN-2020').toISOString();
console.log(newDate)
//2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The function `.replace()` always replaces string, with a string result.

I found the solution to avoid `.replace()` here if anyone has the same problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436561/4693613.